# stop auto compiling in vim+latex-suite

Tags: vim, vim-latex

```
set history=700                      "  How many line Vim should remember
set nocompatible                     "  because vim is not vi
set ignorecase                       "  Searching ignore case, be smart, highlight match
syntax enable

if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
        \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
  autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
endif
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'dense-analysis/ale'
Plug 'fholgado/minibufexpl.vim'                                                     " Buffer explorer
Plug 'gerw/vim-latex-suite'                   , {'for': 'tex'}                      "
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim'                      , {'branch':'release'}
call plug#end()
filetype plugin indent on

augroup FT_LaTex
  autocmd BufReadPost *.tex setlocal filetype=tex
  au FileType tex let b:ale_linters =  ['texlab']
  au filetype tex let b:ale_fixers = ['latexindent', 'remove_trailing_lines', 'trim_whitespace']  
  let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'
  let g:Tex_CustomTemplateDirectory='/home/rudra/Templates/Latex'
  let g:Tex_FoldedMisc = 'preamble,<<<'
  au FileType tex inoremap "" ``"<++><esc>4hi
  au FileType bib inoremap "" ""<++><esc>4hi
  au FileType tex inoremap <<< %<<<
  au QuitPre  *.tex  exe "! latexmk -c"
  au filetype tex syntax region texZone start='\\begin{minted}' end='\\end{minted}'
augroup END

if match (&runtimepath, "coc.nvim") !=-1 
  let g:coc_start_at_startup = 0
  augroup coc
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * :silent CocStart
  augroup end
  let g:coc_user_config = {
        \   'languageserver': {
        \     'latex': {
        \       'command': '/home/rudra/.local/bin/texlab',
        \       'ignoredRootPaths':['~'],
        \       'filetypes': ['tex', 'bib', 'plaintex', 'context'],
        \     },
        \   }
        \ }
else
  echom ('install coc.nvim')
endif


let g:ale_sign_error = 'EE'
let g:ale_sign_warning = 'ww'
let g:ale_set_loclist = 0
let g:ale_set_quickfix = 1
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 1
```

whenever I update tex file, or for mwe, insert a template, I get the following:
[image]

So, I want latex-suite (most probable culprit) to stop auto-compiling, unless asked. How should I do that?